# In washington state can a landlord suddenly rescind an agreed rent renewal with no forewarning?

Tags: contract-law, rental-property, washington, lease-renewal

First section below is the detailed scenario of the requested relevant law(s), and below that is the questioning of the scenario's legality:

---

Abby has a lease that ends in May, and was offered a lease renewal by the property management company in March.  The renewal offer included the choice to renew lease at new rent rate X, switch to a month to month tenancy at much higher rent rate Y, or cease tenancy.  Abby sent agreement to the rent renewal by email on April 1st, which is the way that the agency has requested and accepted rent renewal agreement previously from Abby.

Abby has not recieved an official renewal lease to sign come June, nor any notice that the landlord/agency has changed their mind on the lease renewal offer.  Abby has suddenly been charged month to month rent Y, when expecting the agreed rent X.  Abby has reached out to the agency multiple times in multiple different ways in thelast week.  Abby also put note on paid rent that Abby is seeking the originally agreed rent renewal, and X is the amount Abby paid.

The agency has shown zero response whatsoever to Abby, and is not an onsite management Abby can go talk to in person reliably.  To be very clear per the billing of the agency itself, proper rent is paid for the month, but not the unexpected by Abby/requested by agency additional month to month + late fees.

---

In this scenario, is there an applicable law that makes it illegal to have a sudden change to agreed renewal with no notice? I feel it should be illegal, since the rent charge in June requested is hundreds of dollars different from previous agreement, and feels no different from sudden rent increase with no warning.  However trying to look this scenario up is very difficult, as almost all online info seems to be for the opposite issues (tenant does not want to sign lease, or evictions etc.)

Uncertain if its relevant, but the Abby in this scenario is not behind on rent, has had no compliance, complaints, or payment issues since offer was agreed, and has lived there for around 8 years.  It would be the third lease with this same agency if successfully renewed.

Any knowledge on what the relevant laws would be, or where to check them, is greatly appreciated.  Any feedback or general knowledge on the subject is greatly appreciated.